# Постановка кавычек

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли брать в кавычки слово, употребляемое в переносном значении, если в тексте оговорено, что это значение переносное. То есть, например, "Этот, с позволения сказать, торт..." ("торт" здесь употреблен в переносном значении).
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, кавычки не нужны, потому что на ироничное отношение к предмету, недостойному называться тортом, уже указано другим способом - с помощью вводного предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Для оценки правильности построения предложения нужно представить полностью фрагмент текста. Дело в том, что фраза "с позволения сказать" имеет несколько вариантов значений, но они не относятся к условности названия -  это, скорее, выражение субъективного отношения автора к сказанному.

Фраза "с позволения сказать" употребляется:

А) для принижения оценки важности кого-либо или чего-либо: "Одна театральная, с позволения сказать, критикесса сказала мне..."

Б) (Ирон.) употребляется как выражение отрицательного отношения к кому-, чему-л., мнения о том, что предмет, лицо и т. п., о которых идет речь, недостойны называться своим именем. — А какой у вас вкус, с позволения сказать...

В) оговорка при произнесении неудобных слов:  эта оговорка иногда придается выражению как бы для смягчения, но дает вместо этого — пикантное, двусмысленное, обидное и неудобное: Много въ свѣтѣ риѳмодѣевъ,Все ученыхъ грамотѣевъ,Чтобы всякій вздоръ писать,Съ позволенія сказать. А. С. Пушкинъ. 1817 г.